# How to define a static utility class correctly in Python

Tags: python

I wanted to write a utility class to read from a config file in python.

```
import os,ConfigParser

class WebPageTestConfigUtils:

    configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    configFilePath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'webPageTestConfig.cfg'))

    @staticmethod
    def initializeConfig():
        configParser.read(self.configFilePath)

    @staticmethod
    def getConfigValue(key):
        return configParser.get('WPTConfig', key)

def main():
    WebPageTestConfigUtils.initializeConfig()
    print WebPageTestConfigUtils.getConfigValue('testStatus')

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Upon execution this throws the error.

`NameError: global name 'configParser' is not defined`

Why is python not able to recognize the static member.

Comment: Python is not Java, normally you use a class just if it's something you are going to instantiate. Most probably, you want to write an utility *module* containing free functions.

Comment: Also, you should use `snake_case_names` for variables in Python, not `camelCase`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is almost always better to use `@classmethod` over `@staticmethod`.

Then, `configParser` is an attribute of the `cls` argument:

```
class WebPageTestConfigUtils(object):

    configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    configFilePath = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'webPageTestConfig.cfg'))

    @classmethod
    def initializeConfig(cls):
        cls.configParser.read(cls.configFilePath)

    @classmethod
    def getConfigValue(cls, key):
        return cls.configParser.get('WPTConfig', key)
```

Also note your usage of `self` is replaced by `cls`.

Comment: What is the difference between class method and static method

Comment: Wow! There's a question with the exact same title on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/1931274

Answer (score 1):

Class and instance attributes do not participate in the variable resolution process within a method. If you want to access them, you need to use ordinary attribute lookup syntax:

```
WebPageTestConfigUtils.configParser.read(self.configFilePath)
```

That said, you shouldn't be using a class at all for this. You seem to be used to a language where everything has to be in a class. Python doesn't work that way; you should just be using a module with ordinary functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create static variable in your file, create before class definition. Generally in python static variable declare as UPPERCASE variable name.

For your example you can use

```
CONFIGPARSER = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
CONFIGFILEPATH = (os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'webPageTestConfig.cfg'))

...
...
@staticmethod
def initializeConfig():
    CONFIGPARSER.read(CONFIGFILEPATH)
...
...
```